# How to get the exact JSON structure returned in the gRPC response

Tags: json, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

This is an example illustrating the issue where I'm using [Struct Class](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/struct) as `datasets` type:

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message Datasets {
  string meta_field = 1;
  google.protobuf.Struct datasets = 2;
}
```

And create the object as follows in my `service.py`:

```
ds = example_pb2.Datasets(meta_field = "lorem")

ds.datasets['person'] = { 
   'fname':'foo', 
   'lname':'bar',  
   'addresses*': [
       {
           'number': 12, 
           'post_code': 'ABC'
       },
       {
           'number': 33, 
           'post_code': 'XYZ'
       } 
    ],
    ...
}
```

Where `addresses` here is a dynamic field that can have different values in different scenarios, that's why I did go with the approach of creating `message addresses {...}` in protofile.

My aim is to get the following response from gRPC service:

```
{
  "meta_field": "lorem",
  "datasets": {
    "fname": "foo",
    "lname": "bar",
    "addresses": [
      {
        "number": 12,
        "post_code": "ABC"
      },
      {
        "number": 33,
        "post_code": "XYZ"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But this is what I'm getting instead:

```
{
  "meta_field": "lorem",
  "datasets": {
    "fields": {
      "person": {
        "structValue": {
          "fields": {
            "fname": {
              "stringValue": "foo",
              "kind": "stringValue"
            },
            "addresses": {
              "listValue": {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "structValue": {
                      "fields": {
                        "post_code": {
                          "stringValue": "ABC",
                          "kind": "stringValue"
                        },
                        "number": {
                          "numberValue": 12,
                          "kind": "numberValue"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "kind": "structValue"
                  },
                  {
                    "structValue": {
                      "fields": {
                        "post_code": {
                          "stringValue": "XYZ",
                          "kind": "stringValue"
                        },
                        "number": {
                          "numberValue": 33,
                          "kind": "numberValue"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "kind": "structValue"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "kind": "listValue"
            },
            "lname": {
              "stringValue": "bar",
              "kind": "stringValue"
            }
          }
        },
        "kind": "structValue"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried `map<string, google.protobuf.ListValue>` without success as I keep getting the same result.

Can this be achieved or am I missing something? I'm asking because this service will be consumed by another REST API and the client requested for response to be similar to the short one above.

Comment: even I want to know this. how we can get valid JSON?